# Sort array of hashes

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have this array of hashes:

```
@results = [{:res=>88, :name=>"anna"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"dan"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"cain"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"billy"}]
```

I am trying to sort it by result, then name:

```
@results.sort_by!{ |h| [h.res, h.name] }.reverse!
```

And I get this error:

```
undefined method `res' for {:res=>39, :name=>"cain"}:Hash
```

Any ideas, please.

Comment: Can you clarify what, specifically is unclear about the error message to you? It says that `Hash` doesn't have a method named `res` and if you look at the documentation of the `Hash` class, you will find that there is indeed no method by that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross the condition parameters in order to have sorted by name in the opposite direction:

```
results.sort{ |h1, h2| [h2[:res], h2[:name]] <=> [h2[:res], h2[:name]] }
#=> [{:res=>88, :name=>"anna"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"dan"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"cain"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"billy"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"al"}]


results.sort{ |h1, h2| [h2[:res], h1[:name]] <=> [h1[:res], h2[:name]] }
#=> [{:res=>88, :name=>"anna"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"cain"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"dan"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"al"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"billy"}]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Got it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in JavaScript, you can't call `h.res` on hash to get `res` value. You have to do it using `[]` operator:

```
@results.sort_by! { |h| [h[:res], h[:name]] }.reverse!
```

Comment: One might also avoid the necessity to reverse the result `@results.sort { |h1, h2| [h2[:res], h2[:name]] <=> [h1[:res], h1[:name]] }`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `sort_by` is preferable to `sort` almost every time since it does fewer transformations, once per element instead of two *per comparison*.

Answer (score 1):

This also do the same:

```
@results = [{:res=>88, :name=>"anna"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"dan"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"cain"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"billy"}]
@results.sort_by! { |h| h[:res] }
```

Comment: Yes, but besides "res" I would like to sort by name.

Comment: Then use :name instead of :res

Comment: :( He want to sort by `name` if `res` is equal for 2 records, which is not met by your query.

Comment: :( Also query return ascending order instead of descending order of `res` in above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) (with an argument).

```
@results.max_by(@results.size) { |h| h.values_at(:res, :name) }
  #=> [{:res=>88, :name=>"anna"}, {:res=>39, :name=>"dan"},
  #    {:res=>39, :name=>"cain"}, {:res=>33, :name=>"billy"}]
```